# I use Eclipse Luna and I'm trying out C++, why does it give me errors when I see people doing it fine?

Tags: c++, eclipse

I use Eclipse Luna and I'm trying out C++, why does it give me errors when I see people doing it fine? I have it set to C/C++, I'm using a C++ project and I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Hello World!";
}
```

That's the standard C++ 'Hello World!' program.

I don't have much experience with C/C++ and I don't know why Eclipse is giving me these errors:

Errors (2 items)

Program "make" not found in PATH

Symbol 'cout' could not be resolved

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Windows 8.1, here's a picture of my PC stats. [Stats](http://imgur.com/jovZA3f)

Comment: Do you have a C++ compiler installed?

Comment: I used Help > Install New Software and got CDT but do I have to do something else to use it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you will need to install a compiler and GNU Make. There is a [Guide on Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14222/C-Development-using-eclipse-IDE-Starters-guide)  under "Additional tools required for CDT" that will walk you through the process.